# Can you disable use of Command-F with Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to have a chrome extension prevent a user from using Command-Find / re-program Command-Find to do something different? Thanks!

Comment: Something you can do from here - chrome://extensions/shortcuts

Comment: The extension can add a `keypress` handler that detects Commannd-F and calls `event.preventDefault()`. The user can still use the `Edit->Find` menu.